# Formatting date and time when they are not received as datetime

Tags: sql-server

I am receiving a date and a time field from an access database and they are separate varchar fields.  I am importing the data into an sql database.  I want to display the data as a date time field but I can't get the data to format in the normal manner.  I have come up with a substring to format the data but I am having problems getting it either into a cursor or a loop to get all of the data to update.  I want to format my import table first before I move it to another table in sql.  Here is code that I have for the date and time to format it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Time

```
declare @result varchar(10), @time varchar(6), @hour varchar(2), @min varchar(2), @sec varchar (2);
Select @time = time_of_call from import

Set @hour = substring(@time, 1, 2);
Set @min = substring(@time, 3, 2);
Set @sec = substring(@time, 5, 2);

If @hour < '12' 
    Set @result = @hour + ':' + @min + ' AM';
else if @hour >= '12' 
    Set @result = @hour + ':' + @min + ' PM';

Select @result;
```

Date

```
declare @result varchar(12), @date varchar(8), @year varchar(4), @month varchar(2), @day varchar(2);
Select @date = date_of_call from import

Set @year = substring(@date, 1, 4);
Set @month = substring(@date, 5, 2);
Set @day = substring(@date, 7, 2);

Set @result = @month + '/' + @day + '/' + @year;

Select @result
```

Comment: List some sample data for `time_of_call`

Answer (score 0):

```
--- some sample data
create table import (time_of_call varchar(6), date_of_call varchar(8));
insert into import values ('101112', '20121110');
insert into import values ('134526', '20130201');

--- the query
select cast(date_of_call + ' ' +
            substring(time_of_call, 1, 2) + ':' +
            substring(time_of_call, 3, 2) + ':' +
            substring(time_of_call, 5, 2) as datetime) AsDateTime,
       cast(date_of_call + ' ' +
            substring(time_of_call, 1, 2) + ':' +
            substring(time_of_call, 3, 2) + ':' +
            substring(time_of_call, 5, 2) as datetime) AsString
from import;

----------------------- -----------------------
AsDateTime              AsString
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-11-10 10:11:12.000 2012-11-10 10:11:12.000
2013-02-01 13:45:26.000 2013-02-01 13:45:26.000
```